# How to specify a fallback request mapping in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

We have an endpoint which can return different responses depending on the Accept header. In particular, it can return zip files, video files, or audio files.

Mapping 1:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "endpoint",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = {"video/*", "audio/*"})
```

Mappping 2:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "endpoint",
        method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {"application/zip", "*/*"})
```

This setup will take an `Accept: video/*` and go to mapping 1 (which is what we want). But, `Accept: video/mp4` results in an `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path` exception.

I would have expected that `video/mp4` more closely matches mapping 1 and loads that. Indeed that is exactly what we do want.

We can remove the `*/*` and then `Accept: video/mp4` does go to mapping 1. However, we do need the `*/*` to go to Mapping 2.

Why doesn't `Accept: video/mp4` match Mapping 1 since this is a closer match?

Can we configure this endpoint to have a default method if no other accept header more closely matches? Then we could have mapping 1 only declare that it produces `application/zip`.

We are using Spring Boot 1.5.3.

Comment: You can use the "relative quality factor" like this `produces = {"application/zip", "*/*;q=0.2"}` now `video/mp4` will be matched before `*/*`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @IssamEL-ATIF. I just tried that, but `video/mp4` is still resulting in the `Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path` exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not remove `produces` all together and generate the `Content-Type` within the method and also have an if condition to test the `Accepts` request header? You could call two different methods depending on the request header.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "endpoint", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void doIt(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
  if (request.getHeader("Accept").matches("application/zip"))
    doZip();
  else
    doVideo();
```

Comment: You can directly inject the header, no need to fallback to manual HttpServletRequest handling: `Response doIt(@RequestHeader("Accept") String accept) ..`

Comment: That is ultimately what we did even though it wasn't what I was hoping for from Spring.